# How to log per request / context - Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to migrate an a web app from Google Appengine to a dedicated server and I've got stuck to the logging issue. Basically I would like to organise the logs per request/context(like on GAE) so that I can easily review the errors/trace on each request. The most advanced logging library I could find is the [glog](https://github.com/golang/glog) package but still I can't figure it out how to log per request/context.

Answer (score 0):

Each request gives you a `http.Request`-object to work with.

If you're using [sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions), then you'll have a `sessions.Session`-object to work with.

---

You will want to use those objects to help log per request/context, as they identify the request / session.